# How to create date occurrence between two dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

```
Start Date: 2019-03-03

End Date: 2020-03-02
```

15 days gap between start and end date exclude all Fridays

**Exact Expected output exclude all Fridays**

```
20-Mar-2019 //i need to start with the date 2019-03-03 dont start with the 20 March 2019
07-Apr-2019
24-Apr-2019
12-May-2019
29-May-2019
16-Jun-2019
03-Jul-2019
21-Jul-2019
07-Aug-2019
25-Aug-2019
11-Sep-2019
29-Sep-2019
16-Oct-2019
03-Nov-2019
20-Nov-2019
08-Dec-2019
25-Dec-2019
12-Jan-2020
29-Jan-2020
16-Feb-2020
```

in my code it is not coming  20-Mar-2019 (start date what am giving). Please suggest me where i have mistaken in the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mjshr1d/

FUNCTION CODE

```
function nth(d) {
  if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th'; 
  switch (d % 10) {
    case 1:  return "st";
    case 2:  return "nd";
    case 3:  return "rd";
    default: return "th";
  }
}

function dateToYMD(date) { var strArray=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']; var d = date.getDate(); var m = strArray[date.getMonth()]; var y = date.getFullYear(); return '' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + m + '-' + y; }

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

var cnt = 0;
function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays) {
  var numWorkDays = 0;
  var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  while (numWorkDays < periodInDays && currentDate <= endDate) {
   currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    // Skips friday
    if (currentDate.getDay() !== 5) {
      numWorkDays++;
    }
    if (numWorkDays == periodInDays) {
      numWorkDays = 0;
      cnt++; 
      document.getElementById("first").innerHTML += dateToYMD(currentDate)+"<br/>";
      document.getElementById("second").innerHTML += cnt+nth(cnt)+(cnt==1?" Basic":" Control")+ " Treatment"+"<br/>";

    }
  }
}

var firtsjobstart = new Date("2019-03-03");
var end = new Date("2020-03-02");
var period = 157;
printNextPeriod(firtsjobstart, end, period);
```

Comment: You have commented on most of the answers, adding additional requirements. Please click the edit link below your question and make sure *all* requirements are in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems in your code.

1. You increment the date before checking/printing it.
2. `numWorkDays` is not mutated in the same as `currentDate`.
3. You also have `numWorkDays < periodInDays` which is wrong.

To counter this problem, I modified your `printNextPeriod` function, which by the way should be named `printNextPeriods`

```
function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays) {
    var numWorkDays = 0;
    var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
    while (currentDate <= endDate) { // only this condition is enough as you're modifying the currentDate
        // Skips friday
        if (currentDate.getDay() == 5) { // increase the currentDate and the numWorkDays if the currentDay is friday.. 
            currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
            numWorkDays++;
        }
        if (0 == numWorkDays % periodInDays) { //if its the same day or the periodInDays'th day..
            numWorkDays = 0;
            cnt++; 
            document.getElementById("first").innerHTML += dateToYMD(currentDate)+"<br/>";
            document.getElementById("second").innerHTML += cnt+nth(cnt)+(cnt==1?" Basic":" Control")+ " Treatment"+"<br/>";

        }
        numWorkDays ++;
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);


    }
}
```

here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3ar47g5/10/)

Answer (score 0):

this should work well

```
function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays) {
  var daysRemained = 0;
  var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    if (daysRemained === 0) {
      cnt++;
      daysRemained = periodInDays
      document.getElementById("first").innerHTML += dateToYMD(currentDate)+"<br/>";
      document.getElementById("second").innerHTML += cnt+nth(cnt)+(cnt==1?" Basic":" Control")+ " Treatment"+"<br/>";  
    }
    // Skips friday
    if (currentDate.getDay() !== 5) {
      daysRemained --;
    }
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: sir  its not coming

Comment: sorry, my fault, i edited to the right version, please check

Comment: Code–only answers aren't that helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Comment: This will not work in few cases for example, if the startingDate is on Friday and the mutation to `daysRemained` is different from currentDate.

Comment: @RobG, sounds reasonable, but in this particular case code is quite simple and i guess it  speaks for itself...At least i wouldn't like if someone would start explain Me 3 lines of code, i would get it as humiliation...Anyway i got your point, thanks for sharing it

Comment: @Minato am hiding all fridays from the start and end date calendar..User cant able to select it...

Comment: @DmitryReutov Now i have a dought..If a contract start is 2019-09-01 and ending is 2020-08-31..So every twice a month we need to do two services or jobs.

Comment: @DmitryReutov so when i give the period var period = 13; services are coming 25times in b/w these years..It will be wrong right???In one year contract, only 24 service should come right???

Answer (score 0):

To get the start date printed as well you would need to make sure the condition to print is true on the first iteration, and to ensure the start date is not a Friday (otherwise add 1 day).

As a further improvement I would not use `.addDays(1)` repeatedly, but do the maths to get to the next date in one go. This you can do by identifying how many full weeks fit in the interval-period, and use the remaining number of days to see if you cross a Friday or not.

Here is the suggested code:

```
function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays) {
    var fullWeeks = Math.floor(periodInDays / 6); // number of weeks that fit in period
    var numWorkDays = periodInDays - fullWeeks * 6; // remaining number of days
    var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
    // Make sure not to start on a Friday
    if (currentDate.getDay() === 5) currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);

    while (currentDate <= endDate) {
        cnt++; 
        document.getElementById("first").innerHTML += dateToYMD(currentDate)+"<br/" + ">";
        document.getElementById("second").innerHTML += cnt+nth(cnt)+(cnt==1?" Basic":" Control")+ " Treatment"+"<br/" + ">";

        var daysUntilFriday = (12 - currentDate.getDay()) % 7;
        // Add the full weeks (7 days, always bringing you to the same day-of-the-week)
        // Add the remaining number of days
        // Add one extra day if we cross a Friday in that remaining number of days
        currentDate = currentDate.addDays(fullWeeks * 7 + numWorkDays 
                                          + (numWorkDays >= daysUntilFriday));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying?

Comment: If a contract start is 2019-09-01 and ending is 2020-08-31..So every twice a month we need to do two services or jobs

Comment: so when i give the period var period = 13; services are coming 25times in b/w these years..It will be wrong right???In one year contract, only 24 service should come right???

Comment: I need to do two services per month.So one year 12 months and 24 sevices will come right??

Comment: But in code its showing 25 services when pereiod of days am giving 13

Comment: If a contract start date is 2019-09-01 and ending is 2020-08-31.So each and every month i need to do two services.

Comment: Those are different requirements: either 13 days, or twice per month. With the 13-day rule, it is possible to get 3 hits in a month (when it has 31 calendar days). So are you saying you don't really need the period to be exactly 13 days? You can't have both.

Comment: ya thats the problem...I dont want to show 3 times per month..only two is enough.And sometime i am getting one Month 1 services..You can check the jsfiddle

Comment: But that is not in your question? Will you edit the question, and add that information? What if the period is 17, or something else, then what?

Comment: my requirement is like if user give biannually then yearly two times, if user give twice an month per year..then 24 services

Comment: if the period is 17, only 19 services is coming..and Nov only 1servise  is showing

Comment: But in your question you speak of period of 15 days, and start date 20 March. You have to be more clear in your question. Now you say biannually or twice per month, but surely with other periods, there are other situations. It needs to be clear what you expect **in every case**.

Comment: in our master data, we will feed the job frequency (biannually, weekly,twice a month, daily, or monthly) etc....and their days between service like 13 days gap or if its daily give 1 etc... also will save

Comment: I don't understand how that works. If you store both "biannually" and a number of days, knowing that a year has an odd number of days, how can that work? As I see it, you have complicated your "master data" so that it has rules that are incompatible.

Comment: So i dont want the code for the particular frequency (biannually, weekly,twice a month, daily, or monthly)...i need all for one code to work and without including Fridays

Comment: That I have provided. But now you come with an *extra* requirement, that there should not be 3 hits per month. But my problem is: what are your *extra* rules for all other period values? Is there such a rule when period is 5, 6, ... 14, or 15, or 16, or 17, ... or 300?

Comment: periods for the perticular job frequency i can change and store in database..But this code is not working for all these frequencys..So am asking is there any way to solve this issue??

Comment: What do you mean "is not working for all these frequencies"? It obeys all the requirements that are *in your question*.

Comment: So i need to maintain seprerate code for all these job frequencys???? it should not work for one code????

Comment: I repeat: this code does exactly what you ask for in your question. I don't understand your extra rules.

Comment: No sir there is no rules when period is 5, 6, ... 14, or 15, or 16, or 17, ... or 300

Comment: So there is *only* an extra rule when the input is exactly 13??

Comment: Sir i will put another question..Yesterday i asked this question for biannualy..Today i faced the problem when situation came is twice a month service per year...So when i used this code a month 3 services is coming like that

Comment: In the case of biannually, two times services will correct per year..if start contract 01- jan-2019 means after 6months next service will come july 2019 will come..In this case this code will work.

Comment: It may work for one year, but it will fail in another. I will not insist. It is a matter of mathematics, but we don't seem to understand each other well. I give up. So here is an adapted fiddle, that has a specific condition for when the period is 13 working days: http://jsfiddle.net/smo5jztr/1/

Comment: But you are saying this jsfiddle code wont work in other case means other job frequencys???

Comment: What do you mean "wont work"?? I am not saying that at all.

Comment: sir my question is..in case user selecting other job frequency means is this code will work ???

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200363/discussion-on-answer-by-trincot-how-to-create-date-occurrence-between-two-dates).

Comment: @trincot Sir when thrice a month 36 service will be there know..amgetting only35

Comment: This conversation is not working. I will only repeat that you must edit your question and explain what the rules are. Nowhere you have explained where there is a parameter "thrice a month". The question only speaks about a number of days between chosen days. I will now move on. If you don't do the effort to explain ***in the question*** what these conditions are in the general case (when thrice? when twice?), then don't expect any effort from my side. Note also that in your example (in the question) there sometimes is one date per month, sometimes two. There is no consistency in your question